# Create Kafka topic in Docker works from command line but not from Shell script file

Tags: docker, shell, apache-kafka, docker-compose

I'm trying to create a topic in a Kafka container running in Docker using a shell script file.

docker-compose.yml

```
---
version: '2'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:latest
    container_name: zookeeper
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
    ports:
      - "22181:2181"

  kafka:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest
    container_name: kafka
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper

    ports:
      - "29092:29092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:29092
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
```

init.sh

```
#!/bin/zsh
docker compose up -d
docker exec kafka kafka-topics --create --bootstrap-server localhost:29092 --partitions 1 --replication-factor 1 --topic Test
```

When I run docker-compose the containers start-up fine, but the topic creation fails.

```
[2021-11-04 17:35:07,957] WARN [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:29092) could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
```

However, when I run the same commands in the command line, without any changes, it works fine and creates the topic.

```
Created topic Test.
```

I'm at a loss and reading previous questions on similar issues here hasn't help: mostly they were due to typos or adding quotation marks where they are not needed. I have tried changing the #! to bash, sh, and usr/bin/env (amongst others) to no avail.

Any help appreciated.

Docker version: version 20.10.8
Running on a Mac (Intel)

Comment: You are running containers and without any sleep duration, you are trying to run the command which will always fail. Isolate docker-compose up -d from init.sh. wait for the Broker to be running and ready to connect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested by the error message, the broker is not available (in your case it hasn't started yet).
You could wait for the broker to complete start up process (by looking at the logs with `docker logs -f kafka` or by using a sleep in your script) and then run your command to create the topic:

`docker exec kafka kafka-topics --create --bootstrap-server localhost:29092 --partitions 1 --replication-factor 1 --topic Test`

Alternatively, instead of having to figure out if your broker has completed the initialization process, you could use something like this [official Confluent example](https://github.com/confluentinc/examples/blob/5.1.1-post/microservices-orders/docker-compose.yml#L182-L215).
In this example, [an utility](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-docker-utils/blob/master/confluent/docker_utils/cub.py) is used to wait for a Kafka cluster to be ready.

Comment: This is great, thank you. You were right - it was just a matter of waiting longer. I had tried 10 secs before but as that didn't work I figured it was something else. I'll try to figure out how to use cub in my init.sh file to avoid a hardcoded sleep time.

Answer (score 0):

Where/when are you running the `init.sh` script? Maybe the broker hasn't started yet.

Also, use the internal listener when you want to run commands inside the Docker network

```
docker-compose exec kafka \
  bash -c "kafka-topics --create --bootstrap-server kafka:9092 --partitions 1 --replication-factor 1 --topic Test"
```

Comment: Hi. It was solved it by using a cub command to wait for Kafka, as @Luigi Cerone recommended. Is there a specific reason I should use the internal listener, as you suggested? It worked without it.

Comment: Both will work, only because your listeners are configured that way, however, using the docker service name is best within the Docker network

Answer (score 0):

### Modify `init.sh`

Run the container, `docker-compose up -d`, wait for the broker to run. check with the logs if the application is up and running.

Now `init.sh` should have only `create the topic command`

```sh
#!/bin/zsh
docker exec kafka kafka-topics --create --bootstrap-server localhost:29092 --partitions 1 --replication-factor 1 --topic Test1

docker exec kafka kafka-topics --create --bootstrap-server localhost:29092 --partitions 1 --replication-factor 1 --topic Test2

docker exec kafka kafka-topics --create --bootstrap-server localhost:29092 --partitions 1 --replication-factor 1 --topic Test3
```

Comment: Thank you. You were right about the waiting time, but I need everything in the init.sh file. @Luigi Cerone's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69850294/17318671) helped.

Answer (score 0):

Everyone was right, I had to wait longer (I had tried 10 secs).

As [@Luigi Cerone](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69850294/17318671) suggested, I used `cub` to wait for Kafka to be ready, by adding this line before creating a topic:

```
docker exec kafka cub kafka-ready -b localhost:29092 1 20
```